# random geopoint creation in android

Tags: android, google-maps

How can i generate a geopoint inside a circle of points around my location ? For example i want to generate a geopoint to place a marker into google maps withing a 50 meter range from my location. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[Google Maps: Given a point, how to find all points at a given road distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856992/google-maps-given-a-point-how-to-find-all-points-at-a-given-road-distance)

I guess that's pretty much what you meant?