# How to get all nearby roads in points specified radius?

Tags: google-maps

I have some latitude, longitude and radius in meters and  i need to get all roads names in that radius... The nearest road i can get like this `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=55.685025%2c21.118995&destination=55.685025%2c21.118995&sensor=false&mode=driving`. It would be in `routes[0].legs[0].start_location`. But is it possible to get all roads in 200 meters?

I also found this [Google Maps: Given a point, how to find all points at a given road distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856992/google-maps-given-a-point-how-to-find-all-points-at-a-given-road-distance) in which on screen is show situation almost like mine, but the link is broken.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direction api when a road intersects the circumference. Then you can
subdivide the circle into smaller egments and feed it to the direction api. Here is an example:[How do I calculate a point on a circle’s circumference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839899/how-do-i-calculate-a-point-on-a-circles-circumference).