# Google Maps API: Finding and group closest points to a given point

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to find and group closest points to a given point using Google Maps API v3?

Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a plugin called [marker manager](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/).If you want to go custom see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637023/how-to-calculate-the-latlng-of-a-point-a-certain-distance-away-from-another) for heads up