# locate random latitude, longitude in google map with 1 km distance

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm locating randomly `latitude` and `longitude` in `google map`. I got the latitude and longitude from a table(which consists bunch of latitude and longitude points). I need to select some points, which having 1000 m distance with each and every points.

Is there any method for the above.

Comment: You can find useful information in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637023/how-to-calculate-the-latlng-of-a-point-a-certain-distance-away-from-another

Comment: What do you mean by "locating randomly"?  Are they coming from your database/table?  You want them exactly 1km from each other?  Or within 1 km from some point (the center of your map)?