# Rotate geojson feature with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, proj4js

I have a GeoJson feature that is rendered with leaflet and proj4(ESPG:31467). Now I want to rotate that feature so that it NW corner points to NE, e.g. 90 deg rotation. Is there a way to do this? Or can you give me hints how to address this issue and develop a LL plugin for such functionality.

Cheers, George

Comment: Rotate 90 deg relative to what? It's center?

Comment: Yea, sorry, relative to the center.

Answer (score 0):

[Leaflet.Path.Drag](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag) allows rotation by the user.

Might not provide a direct method for what you want, but certainly has the building blocks to achieve it.

You can also do the transformation yourself, the math is not really complicated: [possible helpful related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967607/rotate-polygon-around-point-in-leaflet-map)