# Get geocoordinate pair given a source coordinate pair and a distance

Tags: javascript, math, geolocation, gis, geo

I want to get the coordinates of a point x meters away from a given point.

I found this code which gives the distance between two coordinate pairs but I want to give one coordinate pair and the distance and return the coordinates of the point away by the given distance.

I think an angle will need to be given too otherwise the result will be a circle. I got the following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters)

```
function measure(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){  // generally used geo measurement function
var R = 6378.137; // Radius of earth in KM
var dLat = lat2 * Math.PI / 180 - lat1 * Math.PI / 180;
var dLon = lon2 * Math.PI / 180 - lon1 * Math.PI / 180;
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
var d = R * c;
return d * 1000; // meters
}
```

Can someone help me do this in JavaScript?

I found another one that uses distance and bearing to do the same but using Google maps API. I don't understand the math behind the conversion and I don't want to include the Google maps API either.

this code is on [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637023/how-to-calculate-the-latlng-of-a-point-a-certain-distance-away-from-another)

Answer (score 0):

From the question you referenced, look at this [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and the section entitled "**Destination point given distance and bearing from start point**"

The math behind this is the haversine formula, which comes from spherical trigonometry.  It is fine for a lot of situations, but it does have its limitations.  In general I usually try to tell people not to try to do their calculations in geolocation/GIS if at all possible, as the math can get nasty much quicker than many realize.  I should note as well that floating point precision can matter here, sometimes a lot.